# Spring @Transactional method executed but takes too long to commit

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

My method annotated with Spring's `@Transactional` executes in 1s by doing around 5K of inserts in 1 Postgres tables.
I use `tableRepo.flush()` and `entityManager.clear()` after every 10 entity inserts.

Here is the code:

```
@Service
public class ImportService {
    ...
    @Transactional
    public void import() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
             for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                 Entity entity = new Entity();
                 entity.setValue(String.format("value %d - %d", i, j));
                 tableRepo.save(entity);
             }
             log.debug("Saved i = {}", i);
             tableRepo.flush();
             entityManager.flush();
             entityManager.clear();
             log.debug("Flushed and cleared i = {}", i);
        }
    }
}


@Service
public class MainService {
    ...
    public void do() {
        importService.import();
        log.debug("Completed");
    }
}
```

However, after that method is executed, Spring's proxy class that called that method, takes around 82s to commit all that into database.
These are the logs with relevant execution times:

```
[DEBUG] 14:02:54,236 ImportService - Saved i = 498
[DEBUG] 14:02:54,239 ImportService - Flushed and cleared i = 498
[DEBUG] 14:02:54,242 ImportService - Saved i = 499
[DEBUG] 14:02:54,245 ImportService - Flushed and cleared i = 499
[DEBUG] 14:02:54,245 org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl:98 - committing
[DEBUG] 14:04:16,868 MainService - Completed
```

Why does it take 82s to commit those changes to database, is there anything I can do to make it faster?

Comment: Only calling flush won't help if you don't clear. The flush will take progressively longer to process.

Comment: @M.Deinum I just updated the question that I also call `entityManager.clear()` after those flushes

Comment: Do proper processing, also loading 10k objects in the 1st level caching isn't helping either. Those are also included in dirty checks (everything is) So instead of loading everything you want to probably use streaming to reduce the load. However as you only describe the code and show nothing (no code, no config etc). How to help you will be impossible to answer.

Comment: @M.Deinum I just updated the question with minimal reproducable code, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For those who enter the same situation, I had a hidden trigger that was executed on Postgres side during commiting.
Since trigger function was executed 5000 times, once for each inserted row, and used unindexed selects, it prolonged the commit for such a long time